# What is 'batchsize' in java's .asparallel() method

Tags: java, eclipse, parallel-processing

Java, more specifically the eclipse collection base, has a method called...

```
asparallel(ExecutorService ES, int batchSize)
```

It takes two arguments, as shown. What is the `batchSize` argument?

**Background**

It is not the the amount of threads that are active. This is defined by the `ExecutorService`. To illustrate, this is the schematic flow of the code I was provided (can't share more).

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(pThreads);
List<Object> mParallelOutput = objectsOfInterest.toList()
    .asParallel(executor, batchsize1)
    .flatCollect(myObject-> MySubComponent.toList()
                               .asParallel(executor, batchsize2)
                               .flatCollect(p -> p.performComputation(myObject));
```

Just as an example,  I have 'a bunch' of computations  ( the `performComputation()` method) that need to be performed for 1-32 objects in the list `objectsOfInterest`. All of the computations can be done in parallel, and we need to be as efficient as possible. In trying to understand the flow, I want to know what the `batchsize` argument is for the `asparallel()` method. In addition, I am not sure whether the double call to asparallel in the sample code above has any added benefit.

Comment: _To illustrate_ I think you could illustrate better if you [edit] your question and post some code, preferrably a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/docs/guide.md :

> The batch size determines the number of elements from the backing collection (FastList or UnifiedSet) that get processed by each task submitted to the thread pool. Appropriate batch sizes for CPU-bound tasks are usually larger, in the 10,000 to 100,000 range.

So, I conclude, in Your case a `batchSize = 1` makes sense. (fully parallel)

Or:

```
 #tasks (submitted to the TP) = collection.size() / batchSize
```

And as I understand the Executor's thread count as the number of tasks, which can be processed simultaneously, I would "align" both values: `#threads ~= #tasks`

Comment: This makes sense.  I have edited my question slightly with a codesnippet. In your experience, does it make sense to call .asparralel twice here? By dividing the work evenly (batchsize1 and batchsize2), I think there was a hope to divide the work. The threadpool is of the type joinfork (newWorkStealingPool), though there is no explicit call to the join or fork statements. Would this, however, still work?